# CMake - Accessing configuration parameters of multiple-configuration generators

Tags: visual-studio, build, cmake, build-system

I'm using CMake to generate a Visual Studio solution. I want my solution to have multiple configurations - x86 Debug/Release and x86_64 Debug/Release.

For each of these configurations, I need to link my project against different versions of my dependencies (i.e. I need the 64-bit, debug build against the 64-bit, debug version of the unit test library).

Here is how I want to do it: I'll place the binary versions of dependencies into folders names after the configurations, for example:

```
<project root>/deps/x86_64_debug/library.lib
```

The question is, how can I tell CMake to look for libraries in the appropriate folder? Are there any CMake variables that indicate the target platform and release/debug status of the "current configuration" for a multi-config generator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please consult documentation for [generator expressions](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html)

> Generator expressions are evaluated during build system generation to
>   produce information specific to each build configuration.