# CMake link_directories from library

Tags: xcode, cmake

I'm trying to link to a library from another library using CMake and Xcode.
This is an issue for any library, but to make things easier to convey, let's use `zlib` as an example.

This seems to work for executables as follows:

```
LINK_DIRECTORIES(${LIB_DIR}/zlib/build/)
ADD_EXECUTABLE(MY_EXECUTABLE ...
```

And it generates an Xcode project with the setting shown below:

[image]

As you can see, the `$(CONFIGURATION)$(EFFECTIVE_PLATFORM_NAME)` bit gets added correctly, to the `zlib` library path.

But if I try to do this:

```
LINK_DIRECTORIES(${LIB_DIR}/zlib/build/)
ADD_LIBRARY(MY_LIBRARY ...
```

`zlib` never gets linked to `MY_EXECUTABLE` when I link it to `MY_LIBRARY`

And `TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES` after `ADD_LIBRARY` allows me to link to `zlib` from `MY_LIBRARY` but I have to specify the full path, which won't work as the configuration (Debug, Release, etc) as well as the effective platform (iphoneos, iphonesimulator, etc) are factors.

What I want to do is to have `zlib` added to the Xcode Library Search Paths, with the `$(CONFIGURATION)$(EFFECTIVE_PLATFORM_NAME)` bit, as shown above.

Comment: If you can you should try to see if your libraries have a CMake modules to easy the process. For zlib for instance : http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/FindZLIB.html .

Comment: About adding Debug, Release, etc. to paths in multi-configuration environments: arguments to [target_link_libraries](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/command/target_link_libraries.html) may use [generator expressions](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html#informational-expressions) with the syntax `$<...>` (also be aware of policy [CMP0003](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/policy/CMP0003.html#policy:CMP0003)). So have you tried `TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(MY_LIBRARY ${LIB_DIR}/zlib/build/$<CONFIG>/...)`?

Comment: @Florian Excellent! That worked like a charm. I used `TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(MY_LIBRARY ${LIB_DIR}/zlib/build/$<CONFIG>$(EFFECTIVE_PLATFORM_NAME)/libz.a` and Xcode replaces `CONFIG` with the appropriate platform. Post this as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Turning my comment into an answer*

CMake does support adding the appropriate configuration to paths in multi-configuration environments with [generator expressions](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html#informational-expressions) (see e.g. [CMake - Accessing configuration parameters of multiple-configuration generators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29045385/cmake-accessing-configuration-parameters-of-multiple-configuration-generators))

And arguments to [target_link_libraries()](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/command/target_link_libraries.html) support the use of generator expressions. So in your case you can make use of the `$<CONFIG>` generator expression which would look something like this:

```
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(MY_LIBRARY ${LIB_DIR}/zlib/build/$<CONFIG>/...)
```

Be aware - if you may have changed some policies - of one note from the `target_link_libraries()` documentation about policies [CMP0003 - Libraries linked via full path no longer produce linker search paths](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/policy/CMP0003.html#policy:CMP0003) and [CMP0004 - Libraries linked may not have leading or trailing whitespace](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/policy/CMP0004.html#policy:CMP0004):

> Note however, that generator expressions will not be used in OLD
>   handling of CMP0003 or CMP0004