# CMake set VisualStudion2010 parameters "Additional Library Directories"

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake

How can I set with CMake in VisualStudio2010 the property "Additional Library Directories".

Example:

%(AdditionalLibraryDiretories) = "d:/librarys/wnt/i386/debug/"

[image]

configuration parameter  -> linker -> general-> "Additional Library Directories"

I tried this and it doesn't work.

```
link_directories("d:/librarys/wnt/i386/debug/")
```

Comment: I just tested it with VS2012 / CMake 3.3.0 and it seems to work fine. If you put `link_directories("d:/librarys/wnt/i386")` before my `add_executable(...)` call I get a "Additional Library Directories" property with `d:/librarys/wnt/i386;d:/librarys/wnt/i386/$(Configuration);%(AdditionalLibraryDirectories)`. See [`link_directories()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/command/link_directories.html) documentation.

Comment: THX Florian it works. My problem was that **add_execute** before **link_directory**

Comment: The problem now is that **AdditionalLibraryD‌​irectories** depends on the Configuration. There is an other path for **debug** libraries than **release** libraries

Comment: Please see my last comment. I removed your `debug` part there, because CMake does - to cover libraries depending on Config - include two variants of what you have given in `link_directories()`: `d:/librarys/wnt/i386` and `d:/librarys/wnt/i386/$(Configuration)`. And just a hint: I never needed `link_directories()` in any of my projects. So I'm wondering - admittedly without knowing your use case - if you could not use [`target_link_libraries()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/command/target_link_libraries.html) instead?

Comment: The pathes doesn't named **d:/librarys/wnt/i386/ $(Configuration) = debug** instead e.g. **d:/librarys/wnt/i386/fooba**.

Comment: That's the point. `link_directories()` has a very limited scope with a dedicated set of functionality, so I would do something like `target_link_libraries(MyExe debug "d:/librarys/wnt/i386/fooba/foo.lib")`. But if you really want to force it I can only think of extending the linker flags directly: call `set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG} /LIBPATH:\"d:/librarys/wnt/i386/fooba\"")` after your `project(...)` command. Then I get `%(AdditionalLibraryDirectories);d:/librarys/wnt/i386/fooba`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Turning my comments into an answer*

**What does `link_directories()` cover?**

I tested it with VS2012 / CMake 3.3.0 and if you put your [`link_directories(...)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/command/link_directories.html) before your [`add_executable(...)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/command/add_executable.html) call it seems to work fine.

```
link_directories("d:/librarys/wnt/i386")

get_directory_property(_my_link_dirs LINK_DIRECTORIES)
message(STATUS "_my_link_dirs = ${_my_link_dirs}") 

add_executable(...)
```

Everything you add with `link_directories()` will be appended to the directory property [`LINK_DIRECTORIES`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/prop_dir/LINK_DIRECTORIES.html) and assigned to whatever targets are listed afterwards.

In the upper example I get in Visual Studio "Additional Library Directories" property:

> d:/librarys/wnt/i386;d:/librarys/wnt/i386/$(Configuration);%(AdditionalLibraryD‌​irectories)

CMake does - to cover libraries depending on Config - include two variants of what you have given in link_directories(): `d:/librarys/wnt/i386` and `d:/librarys/wnt/i386/$(Configuration)`.

**What if you need more flexiblity?**

If your `debug`/`release` path names are not matching the VS configuration name (e.g. `fooba` for `debug`), then you can't use `link_directories()`. One approach would be to extend the linker flags directly:

```
project(...)
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG} /LIBPATH:\"d:/librarys/wnt/i386/fooba\"")
```

Then I get in the `Debug` config properties:

> %(AdditionalLibraryDirectories);d:/librarys/wnt/i386/fooba

For the lack of flexibility of `link_directories()` I normally only use the [`target_link_libraries()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/command/target_link_libraries.html) command. E.g.:

```
target_link_libraries(MyExe debug "d:/librarys/wnt/i386/fooba/foo.lib")
```

would give in the Debug "Additional Dependencies" property:

> kernel32.lib;user32.lib;gdi32.lib;winspool.lib;shell32.lib;ole32.lib;oleaut32.lib;uuid.lib;comdlg32.lib;advapi32.lib;d:\librarys\wnt\i386\fooba\foo.lib

**References**

- [CMake link_directories from library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31153019/cmake-link-directories-from-library)
- [cmake - Global linker flag setting (for all targets in directory)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32698580/cmake-global-linker-flag-setting-for-all-targets-in-directory)